# Downloading Zip File with Poco::Compress and FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to download a zip file using $http service in angularJS, I ve set:

```
responseType = arraybuffer 
contentType = application/zip
```

Hence my file is corrupted somehow. I've searched around some threads suggest to responseType='blob' but it did not help. I am able to see the body binary content though.

My server codes:

```
response.setStatusAndReason(HTTPResponse::HTTP_OK);
response.setKeepAlive(true);
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.set("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"logs.zip\"");
Poco::Zip::Compress compress(response.send(),false);
compress.addRecursive(Constants::LOG_FOLDER,
                      Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CM_DEFLATE,
                      Poco::Zip::ZipCommon::CL_SUPERFAST,
                      false, "server_logs");
compress.close();
```

I am using a third party api [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js). I can download properly other files. I just have this issue with zip files.

Client-Side Codes:

```
var headers = response.headers();
     var filename = "";
     var disposition = headers['content-disposition'];
     if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
         var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
         var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
         if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = 
         matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
      }
    var file = new File([response.data], filename, {type: headers['content-
    type']});
    saveAs(file);
```

Comment: Show the JavaScript where you're using FileSaver. FileSaver is useful for downloading data that is generated or edited on the client-side. Here, it looks like you're preparing the download entirely on the server-side, making FileSaver unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, I am preparing the file on server-side. send the content as stream in response data.

Comment: If you navigate directly to your download URL in your browser, does it correctly download the zip file as an attachment? If that's the case, you can just provide a link directly to the download URL - no need for Angular or FileSaver.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK, i found out that my streamed data was corrupted somehow if i pass response.send() directly into compress function provided by Poco.